# How to open messenger (facebook) with pre-populated link?

Tags: android, ios, facebook, mobile, web

I'm trying to open facebook messenger app (android or ios) with pre-populated link when user click on share button on my website. I'm already use whatsapp share, and its pretty simple. There are link whatsapp://send?text=Hello%20World. Looks like facebook don't have any simple way to populate message via deep link.

But you can share via "Share" button in mobile google chrome, and its works in a way i'm need. How its working? Can i add same behavior on my web page?

Thank you.

Comment: Use the Send button or Message dialog explained at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android#message

Comment: Thank you, but i'm asking about web version. Send button don't work in mobile web. Message dialog don't work in web version.